# SilverStripe 3 UserForms - Emails not sending or being received. How to trouble shoot

Tags: forms, phpmailer, silverstripe

I'm using UserForms 4.6 with SilverStripe 3.7.2.
Everything works except for the email actually sending and coming into the mail inbox. The form goes to the success page and the form data is saved in the CMS submissions just no email.
I've made sure the from address is the same the domain. 
I get no error on the site.

I can see this 404 error in the cPanel logs: **/UserDefinedForm_Controller/ping**

How can I troubleshoot this?

[UserForms Module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms)

[Live Site](https://www.latham-street.com/contact)

Comment: You can enable logging, which might help you to work out why your emails aren't sending. https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/debugging/error_handling/. Maybe enable the email log, that way you can also ensure that your log emails are sent (if not, it's a web server configuration issue)

Comment: are your email settings correct? like SMTP creds? see https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/email/#configuration

Comment: Log in to the website's cPanel and use the track delivery tool to check the emails are being sent and what is happening with them.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out in my case that the Spam filter was stopping them getting through. Nothing todo with UserForms or SS.